# Vim-Latex: Appendix gets folded into previous section

Tags: vim-latex, appendix

I have main.tex file and an appendix.tex file. I use `include` command to insert the appendix file. No problems with latex, but vim-latex folds the `\include{appendix}` statement into the previous section. How can I avoid this?

Here is the MWE: main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.1 in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\title{ State of the Art }
\author{\bf My Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Some introduction

\section{Main Section}
Main content

\subsection{subsection}
Subsection content

\newpage
\include{appendix}
\end{document}
```

and the appendix.tex

```
\appendixpage
\begin{appendices}
    \section{Appendix Header}

\end{appendices}

\bibliography{bibfile}
```

Comment: By changing the fold rules. Better place to ask is probably: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fake sections as described in [8.2 Customizing what to fold](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-what-to-fold.html) of the documentation can be used like `%%fakesection Appendix` such that

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\title{ State of the Art }
\author{\bfseries My Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Some introduction

\section{Main Section}
Main content

\subsection{subsection}
Subsection content

%%fakesection Appendix
\newpage
\include{appendix}
\end{document}
```

folds up as

```
 +      3 lines: Preamble: \documentclass[11pt]{article}---------------------
 \begin{document}
 \title{ State of the Art }
 \author{\bfseries My Name}
 \date{\today}
 \maketitle
 +      3 lines: \section{Introduction}--------------------------------------
 +      6 lines: \section{Main Section}--------------------------------------
 +      3 lines: %section Appendix-------------------------------------------
 \end{document}
```

Comment: voila !!! works excellently